# Submit a form without refreshing a page using ajaxForm

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a total novice so please excuse my ignorance.

I have website with a php shopping cart that refreshes to the cart page when something is added to to the cart. I want to modify it so that when a product is added, the cart updates in the background and the product page does not refresh but updates the html in various divs with unique id's.
I have managed to achieve this but I am sure that there must be a simpler way as my solution involves a loop that trawls through all the forms on the product page rather than just updating the divs from the form that was submitted.

Here's my JavaScript which is inside the `<head>` tags of the product page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("[id^=ectform]").ajaxForm({   // any form id beginning with ectform
          success:function(){
          $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
          $("#div1").load("jsrefresh.php");  // update html in div in minicart
             for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {     // count holds the number of forms on the page
                var d = "#glc" + i; //  div id to update
                var f ="#gld" + i;   // another div id to update
                var e = eval("z" + i);  // product id
       $(f).html('loading...').load("jsrefreshincart.php",{ prodynum: e, divno: d});
      };
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

The script utilises ajaxForm to wait for the successful submission of any form with an Id beginning with ectform. On success, The form is submitted to the cart script which updates the cart contents and then ajax .load is used to call jsrefresh.php which echoes back the updated html to a div in a  mini cart which is displayed at the top of the  screen. Then (this is the bit that needs doing properly) jsrefreshincart.php is called in a loop ( the variable count holds the total number of forms on the page ) which updates html in all divs within all the forms on the page with information about how many items are in the cart and how much they cost.
Is there any way of doing this without the loop as only the divs within the form that was submitted need to be updated ?

Answer (score 1):

**The major problem here is not that you have a loop, but that you have a server-call inside of it.** The best way to handle this is to change the way that `jsrefreshincart.php` handles calls from the server. Instead of having multiple calls *inside* the loop, collect all the data and have a single call *outside* the loop.

I don't think that's something the jQuery Form plugin can handle; rather, you'll probably have to write some custom code (like below):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=ectform]").on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('[id^=gld]').html('loading...'); // Trigger all loading messages simultaneously
      var formNums = [];
      for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        formNums.push(i);
      }
      $.post({
        $(this).attr('action'), // Where to send the form action
        formNums: formNums, // The data to send when submitting the Ajax call
        refreshCartData // The callback used to refresh the page
      });
    });
  });

  // Called automatically when the server responds with data
  function refreshCartData(data) {
    // Loop through all forms and update them
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // Update HTML
      $('#gld' + data[i].formNum).html(data[i].cartHTML);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Your `jsrefreshincart.php` should return data for all of this. For example:

```
<?php

// Used to load the cart data - I'm sure you have something similar
require_once('cart.php');
// Send everything back as JSON
header('Content-type: application/json');
// Initialize the data to send back
$data = array();
// Iterate over all data send to the server
foreach ($_POST['formNums'] as $formNum) {
  $data[] = array(
    // The unique ID for the form number
    'formNum' => $formNum,
    // Again, however you get the view data for your cart line items works fine
    'cartHTML' => Cart::getCartHTML($formNum)
  );
}
// Spit out the JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
```

Some additional suggestions:

- Your variables d, e, and f in your original code are not necessarily all updated during the Ajax round-trip
- You need to add more commenting and indentation - it seems simple, but proper documentation is the best way to communicate your problems to other developers
- Consider using a different way to keep track of data besides a "`count` of forms" - classes can work too
- My assumption is that anything starting with an ID of `ectform` is a form to have this functionality captured in; if this is not the case, parts of the above solution might not make sense

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the suggestion by Dykotomee (thank you), it gave me the idea how I could amend my script to work without the loop:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ // when DOM is ready
   $("[id^=ectform]").on('submit', function(e) {  // on submission of any form with id beginning "ectform"
    e.preventDefault();             // prevent the form itself submitting the data
      var subformid = $(this).attr('id'); // set variable with the id of the submitted form
       $(this).ajaxSubmit({     // submit the form via ajax which will add the product to the cart
        success:function(){    //on successful submission of the form
         $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // turn off cache so the updates will refresh on all browsers
         $("#div1").load("jsrefresh.php");  //  load div in mini cart with new updated cart quantity
        var str = subformid.replace("ectform", "");  // trim subformid to leave just the end digits and call this variable str
       var d = "#glc" + str;   // not important for purposes of explanation
      var f ="#gld" + str;  // f is the id of the div in the submitted form to be updated 
    var e = eval("z" + str);  // e is the product number
$(f).html('Adding item to Cart...').load("jsrefreshincart.php",{ prodynum: e, divno: d}); // send data to jsrereshincart.php and load updated html into div f.
      }
    });
   });
 });
</script>
```

I used ajaxSubmit instead of ajaxForm which allowed me to trigger the submission of the form using `$("[id^=ectform]").on('submit', function(e) {.......`
I was then able to catch the id of the form submitted with `var subformid = $(this).attr('id');`
Now I had the id of the submitted form , I was able to use ajax .load to get the updated cart HTML into the div in that particular form rather than looping through all the forms and updating them one by one.
The script now only makes a total of 2 server calls per form submission. My previous script made up to 50 calls when a maximum of 25 products/forms were displayed on the products page.
I could modify this script and the php scripts to do everything with a single call but other pages on the site don't have products, just the mini cart so it's easier to keep the scripts separate.