# how to make a div load on submit without refreshing the page using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is my code that works fine, but it has to reload on every time submitted. I want to reload the `comments.php`  on every time submit button is clicked.

What should I write in JavaScript?

**Index.php:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <form action="" method="post" id="reply" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
    <div class="input-group">
      <input   type="text" placeholder="say something" class="form-control" name="comment"/>
      <br/>
      <button class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
 
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //php goes here
  }      
?>

<div>
  <?php include("comments.php") ; ?> 
  // i  want  to make this reload on every submit 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you googled it?

Comment: If you don't want to refresh your page, first change type="button" instead of "submit"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit a form without refreshing a page using ajaxForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881638/submit-a-form-without-refreshing-a-page-using-ajaxform)

Comment: @ppasler i asked how to load a specific  div  on submit ...... i did not ask how to  submit form without refreshing whole page

Comment: @truespeaker why are you not responding to the answers but responding to comments?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunc(){
$.ajax({
url:"comments.php",
data:$("input").val(),
method:'post',
success:function(response){
},
error:function(error,message){
}
});

}

<form action="javascript:myfunc()"......>
```

this is with jquery

Answer (score 0):

This question uses jquery. If you dont know it, visit http://jquery.org for more information:

Add a div around the comments.php:

```
<div id="comments">
  <?php include("comments.php") ; ?> 
</div>
```

Now you can catch the submit and replace it with an ajax call+ reload the comments:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#reply").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax();//todo for you. I cannot write this with this rare information
    $("#comments").load("comments.php");//the magic part
    return false;//prevent the real submit
  }):
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery load() Method.

The jQuery load() method loads data from the server and place the returned HTML into the selected element. This method provides a simple way to load data asynchronous from a web server.

**The parameters of the load() method has the following meaning:**

1. The required URL parameter specifies the URL of the file you want to
   load.
2. The optional data parameter specifies a set of query string
       (i.e. key/value pairs) that is sent to the web server along with the
       request.
3. The optional complete parameter is basically a callback function
   that is executed when the request completes. The callback is fired
   once for each selected element.

Your html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#box").load("comments.php");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="comments">

    </div>
    <button type="button">Load Comments</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Comments.php**

```
<?php


    //content here

    echo "I'm loaded";

    ?>
```